# Are there Salesforce to Salesforce limits?

Tags: salesforce-to-salesforce

Are there limits to how many source orgs can be connected to a target org? Building out instances for 10 or more different nonprofits (source orgs) that are a part of a national network of nonprofits. Those orgs are all supported by a single national nonprofit (target org). Looking to establish Salesforce to Salesforce connections that would allow for the 10 or more source orgs to push selected info from standard and custom objects to the target org but haven't been able to find any information on if there are limits to the number of allowed connections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [KB 000314973](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314973&type=1&mode=1):

> For Salesforce to Salesforce (S2S) transaction, there would be an API call to update data from and to other orgs. It does count against daily API limits.

This means that you're subject to API limits, meaning that for most orgs, you can't synchronize more than a few million records/edits per day.

There is no limit to the number of connections you can have, but many connections will limit how many records you can synchronize.

Comment: I've got 40+ production orgs connected to one central org with Salesforce to Salesforce. It's got close to 4M synced records and while S2S is one of the biggest API users, we haven't had a problem with hitting API call limits. I'm just hoping there's not a limit to the number of PNRCs!